# Tridion 2011 SP1 : Facing Issue while creating client application using Core Services

Tags: wcf, web-services, tridion, tridion-2011

I have created a small application using Core Services and it is working fine when we run it on the CMS Server. But when I host it on my client machine and run, it is not working.

I checked the webservices whether client able to contect webservices.
URl of the webservice - IP:5001/webservices/CoreService2011.svc
This url shows me a page having content like

> You have created a service.
>
> To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:
>
> svcutil.exe http://vmadtridiecmesx.ecmlab.com:5001/webservices/CoreService2011.svc?wsdl
>
> This will generate a configuration file and a code file that contains the client class. Add the two files to your client application and use the generated client class to call the Service. For example:

And from here if I clicked on the link "http://vmadtridiecmesx.ecmlab.com:5001/webservices/CoreService2011.svc?wsdl
".It gices me the error.

> Unknown Host
>
> ---
>
> ### Description: Unable to locate the server named "vmadtridiecmesx.ecmlab.com" --- the server does not have a DNS entry. Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists. Double-check the name and try again.

Is this the issue?
If not can some one help me to know what is the exact problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried adding the domain in your hosts file with the i.p?  I think the error message is pretty clear.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, it looks like you cannot contact that machine because it doesn't have a DNS entry (so it cannot look up the IP).

If you go to the CoreService2011.svc?wsdl URL, you should be getting the WSDL XML back - not an error.

Are you using the IP in your configuration? Or the machine name?

Either way, I'd advise fixing the DNS issue so that the CM machine can be used by your clients.

Comment: I am using IP in config file <endpoint address="http://172.19.68.113:5001/webservices/CoreService2011.svc/wsHttp" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttp" contract="TridionCoreService.ISessionAwareCoreService" name="wsHttp">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="172.19.68.113"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>

Comment: You are missing the protocol in the address attribute ("http://") - maybe that's the issue?

Comment: yes Jeremy you are correct.Protocol is there in the config file

Answer (score 3):

Check if you can connect to the host with the specified port using TELNET. I suspect that the ports are closed, and this might be a firewall issue.

Comment: Yeah, I'm leaning towards that as well - 5001 isn't exactly a standard port :)